# Where is the code of filter function in Python?

Tags: python

I am using function `filter` in Python, and using `Pycharm` as an IDE. When I click on function name to take a look to the code I only see this:

```
def filter(function_or_none, sequence): # known special case of filter
    """
    filter(function or None, sequence) -> list, tuple, or string

    Return those items of sequence for which function(item) is true.  If
    function is None, return the items that are true.  If sequence is a tuple
    or string, return the same type, else return a list.
    """
    pass
```

Where is the code of this function?

Comment: Do you mean, implementation of `filter`?

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d0d3e99120b19a4b800f0f381b2807c93aeecf0e/Python/bltinmodule.c#L601